# How can I use VueJS in HTML that is injected after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We're migrating a legacy front-end to VueJS 2. So far, it's using HTML and JS to fetch modals and inject those in the DOM. We'd like to migrate one specific (and very simple) modal.

That modal is a reset password modal. It is, for now, fetched from the login modal using the legacy logic (which is a native onclick call). We'd like the login modal to interact with VueJS and display the reset password modal.

But the problem is, when we originally load the HTML, the login modal is not in the DOM (until we display it). So it seems VueJS event handlers won't trigger at all.

How can I use VueJS in this login modal which is injected after the page is loaded ?

Here's some pseudo code to illustrate my question :

```
# OLD
// HTML
<!-- Button displaying the login modal -->
<button onclick="displayModal('login')">Log in</button>

<!-- Login modal (loaded only when user clicks the button) -->
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <button onclick="displayModal('reset-password')">Reset password</button>
</div>

// Native JS
function displayModal(name) {
    var result = fetchModal(name);
    removeCurrentModal();
    injectModal(result);
}

# NEW
// HTML
<!-- Login modal (loaded only when user clicks the button) -->
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <!-- This doesn't do anything even though it works when it exists on page load instead -->
    <button @click="modals.passwordReset.show = true">Reset password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m not sure this is possible. Do you use Vue2 or Vue3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I use Vue 2.

Comment: Why do you need event handlers to work before it's mounted?

Comment: Do you mean when the login modal is open the click event just doesn't fire?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Yes, when the login modal is injected after the page is loaded, the `@click` event doesn't fire at all.

Comment: How do you inject the login modal?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Using native javascript, I simply append it to the DOM.

Comment: That's likely why it doesn't work, I'd suggest [using a `v-if` condition](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to open it. Just depends on if your project allows it.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Yes of course, but the login modal is legacy code, and we wanted to migrate a more simple modal first. I guess migrating only the displaying part would work but that means also migrating other modals which can be displayed thanks to the login modal ! Thanks for the help.